# Fastest way to convert numeric chars to int

Tags: java, char, data-conversion

From looking over here and other websites I know there are two common ways to convert a numeric `char` value like `'5'` to an `int` value:

1. Using `Character.getNumericValue()`
2. Subtracting the number with the ASCII value for `'0'`; i.e. `int number = num - '0'`, where `num` is a `char` value.

Which of these two approaches is the fastest and most efficient?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to do micro-optimization here? Let me just leave a note that this might be a bad thing in general. Usually you would rather prefer readability over getting 1 nanosecond more speed.

Comment: Premature optimization is root of all evils.

Comment: `Character.getNumericValue()` should be *slower*, since it takes *Unicode* into account, e.g. `Character.getNumericValue((char) 0x00B3)` returns `3` since `0x00B3` corresponds to "superscript 3", when `num - '0'` is just subtract two `int`s

Comment: First of all `Character.toNumericValue()` is not a method. It is `Character.getNumericValue()`, Secondly why are you looking for micro-optimization?

Comment: @Zabuza No, I was just wondering as I wanted to know if one was a lot more slow than the other. I use it a lot so was wondering if I was using the most efficient one.

Comment: I see, the difference is so minimal that it really does not matter much. It is extremely likely that any other statement in your code is much much much more slowing down your app than this, for example a single `System.out.println`. If you are curious, measure your code using a benchmark-suite like jmh (part of the JDK).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The two versions are not equivalent:

   - The `Character.getNumericalValue(...)` methods work for a variety of characters that represent digits or numbers, and it will return `-1` or `-2` in cases where the character doesn't represent a non-negative integer.
   - The `num - '0'` approach only gives the correct answer for the codepoints that correspond to the ASCII characters `'0'` through `'9'`.  For all other codepoints or codeunits, it gives a meaningless value.
2. The `num - '0'` version will be faster.  This is clear from looking at the source code for `getNumericalValue(...)`.
3. While the difference is significant in relative terms, it is very small in absolute terms.

---

I concur with the comments that say that this is most likely a *premature* optimization.

It is also an *incorrect* optimization in some contexts.

---

> I use it a lot so was wondering if I was using the most efficient one.

This is definitely premature optimization :-)

The number of times you *write* a particular code sequence is unrelated to performance of the code sequence when is *executed*.  A section of code is only worth optimizing if the time spent executing it makes a significant difference to your entire application.

Answer (score 6):

Well, `Character.getNumericValue()` takes *Unicode*, *radix*, *case*, *culture* into account:

```
 '0' ->  0 // Same as number - '0'
 '9' ->  9 // Same as number - '0'
 'A' -> 10 // Hexadecimal 0xA == 10
 'f' -> 15 // Hexadecimal 0xF == 15
 '³' ->  3 // Unicode superscript 3
 '⒇'-> 20 // Unicode enclosed alphanumeric 20 
 '۵' ->  5 // Persian digit 5
 '*' -> -1 // Doesn't have any corresponding integer value
 '⅚' -> -2 // Even if 5/6 fraction Unicode character is a number, it's not integer
```

while

```
number - '0'
```

is just a subtraction of two `int`s. That's why `Character.getNumericValue()` is inevitably *slower* (some nanoseconds, is it worth optimizing?). But, please, note, that in `'A', 'f', '³', '*'` etc. cases you are going to have *wrong asnwers* with `number - '0'` code.